# When is it appropriate to have non-HttpOnly cookies on your domain?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, httponly

I have read the [OWASP information](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) and also a range of articles including Jeff Atwood's [Protecting Your Cookies](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/) article and I still feel I need to understand HttpOnly cookies better.

This came about because I needed to add some [Google Adword tracking code](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031) to a site. This javascript needed to set and read a cookie on the website's domain and I assumed that this was an issue. The website is a .Net application with `httpOnlyCookies="true"` in the web.config, so I assumed that the best approach would be to replace the javascript and write the cookie from the backend to ensure that the generated cookie was HttpOnly. I could then easily read the cookie in the server-side too.

I understand that setting the HttpOnly of a cookie property largely prevents a cookie from being read and manipulated by the client. But what I don't understand is:

- Given the example above, would there have been a problem with me using the javascript implementation?
- Would it still have been ok to write the cookie using javascript (but still read it using the server-side)? I'm thinking not as the cookie is then not a HttpOnly cookie
- If I have done the right thing (moving everything to a server-side implementation), why are Google Analytic cookies always implemented as non-HttpOnly cookies? Surely they pose a security issue too?

So as the title says, I guess what I'm asking is - when (if ever) is it appropriate to have non-HttpOnly cookies on your domain?

Comment: Cookies that retain information that's not of a secure nature (like, a cookie that remembers the last-used browser window size) are really not a security issue. Who cares if the information is leaked?

Comment: Any time you _want_ JavaScript to be able to read the cookie, you need it to not be HttpOnly. You don't want to do this with, for example, an authenticated session key.

Comment: @mah Yes that is fairly obvious :) The question is when is it appropriate to use a non-HttpOnly cookie? If I can handle all my cookie implementations server-side, should I? Or is it overkill? If so why?

Comment: To answer the question you must first consider the purpose of the cookie. If it's related to a user preference in how something gets displayed then perhaps JavaScript handling is a better solution. If instead it's a user preference concerning what data gets displayed (filtering out data perhaps) then a server side solution might be better (to limit bandwidth) but HttpOnly is probably not important (since there's no security ramification -- or shouldn't be). HttpOnly is really only necessary for things that are security sensitive.

Comment: So a HttpOnly requirement can be disregarded for *any* cookies that contain non-sensitive information. It's that simple?

Comment: Yes, it's that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is much more straightforward than I assumed. According to the comments left by @mah above, flagging a cookie as `HttpOnly` is redundant when the cookie contains non-sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

The `httpOnly` option was response to JavaScript tricks to steal user's **session cookie**. It was because the session cookie is a temporary credential that allows you access to user's logged-in session on the server.

In case of any other, non-session cookies it really depends on your own risk assessment. If you're not really concerned about slightly increased exposure without `httpOnly` or you just have a business need to access their values from JavaScript, just ignore this option.

Some security scanners or incompetent pentesting teams will report missing `httpOnly` flags for each cookie just because it's trivial to spot and allows them to easily inflate their report. But explaining the actual purpose and origin of `httpOnly` should be sufficient to counter that.